# How does the CRediT system work?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I'm preparing a submission to Royal Society Biology Letters, and they also require that each author's [CRediT contribution](https://casrai.org/credit/) is provided.
I'm not familiar with this (I usually publish in engineering venues that do not require detailed contributions), could someone clarify a few things?

There are four options for each category: *lead*, *equal*, *supporting*, and not ticking the checkbox.

**Question 1**
I'm assuming that not ticking a checkbox is a valid entry for "no contribution" for that category. If a category is not very relevant for the study, can it be skipped entirely?

**Question 2**
Are *lead* and *equal* mutually exclusive? Or can they be used to split contributions into three levels? Same between *supporting* and *equal*. (Author 1: Lead, Author 2: Equal, Author 3: Equal, Author 4: Supporting 5:Supporting)?

*edit:* in a bizarre turn of events, when I logged back in the CRediT accreditation was no longer in the system, and instead there was a field for freetext in which to write a statement of contributions, following RS's own [guidelines](https://royalsociety.org/journals/ethics-policies/openness/). No idea what happened there.

Comment: Does it really work?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "work". Does it incentivize people to have this conversation earlier, add clarity to author contributions, and to what should be considered a sufficient contribution for co-authorship? Probably. Does it eliminate free-ride authorship without sufficient contribution entirely? Quite certainly not. Is it a good requirement for journals to have? I think so.

Answer (score 1):

Journals use a variety of formats for reporting author contributions. This content is like a conflict of interest statement—it's not typically evaluated as part of the peer review, but more a contractual reassurance in case of later concerns such as whether an author is added with no contribution.

I've used CRediT statements in several published papers. I don't know a citation for my claims below, but I strongly suspect:

1. Yes
2. Not mutually exclusive